# How do I view objective-c library header files in xcode

Tags: xcode, header-files

With all of the programming I have ever done in my entire life I have found myself banging my head against the wall shouting "Show me the header file! Just show me the header file!"
   I have decided that I will take the summer off and only write objective-c in Xcode for iPhones.
   I want to be able to read the header files for various objective-c libraries for the purpose of familiarizing myself with them.  The one I want right now is UITouch.h, but really I just want to be able to view whatever ".h" file I need to know more about.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: That answers my question perfectly.  Of all of these answers the frameworks one is my favorite.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new project, import the frameworks, or open up the frameworks folder of your current project. The headers will be inside those packages.

Answer (score 2):

Cmd-shift-O to Open Quickly, then start typing the class name.

Comment: Thanks — this shortcut is *really* useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should have a #import or #include statement to import/include the header file. Holding the Command key, click the import/include statement to view the header. Also, you can Command-click on a symbol to jump to the header file that defines it.

Alternatively, you can select the pull down menu at the far left of the jump bar, and go down to the "includes" submenu and select the header file to view.

Comment: OP talks about viewing UITouch.h, which you typically don't explicitly include, since it's included with UIKit. This goes for non-framework headers, though.

Comment: When you go to UIKit.h you can continue down the tree of includes and go as deeply as you need to get to the file of interest. In this case, UITouch.h is immediately beneath UIKit.h.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on a symbol and select **Jump to Definition** in the popup menu. That brings you to the header file where the symbol is defined.